# Gap between top mount sink and new counter

Tags: kitchen-sink

Is there anything that can be done about this gap? This is a fire clay sink and it seems to be warped a little.

[image]

Comment: return the sink to the seller for replacement

Comment: I would say "warped quite a bit" but call it what you like.

Answer (score 6):

If it is warpage (that should be a word)... you can sand out that area given this isn't stone.   You could sand a groove for that and set the back into it.  I am just look at a picture but it looks like the back of the sink has a little bend on it (is the other side look exactly the same?).   The first 80% seems straight though.

So I am not sure if that bend is causing it not to sit flat or if there is something next to the sink that is protruding where it shouldn't be... or both.   Can you wiggle the sink around?   If it is ultra tight your cutout may need to be a little bigger.

Just FYI - fire clay sinks always have small deformities.   Most too tiny to notice.  I did get one where the bottom was jacked and basically at a 15-20% angle - you know where you connect your plumbing.   I had already secured it to the top weeks before and had to hit it with belt sander for about 20 mins before it was flat enough to not leak.   You can sand the sink but I personally wouldn't given the picture here.
In the end this isn't the end of the world.   The gap isn't humongous - yes bigger than normal or bigger than you want.    When caulking this (clear silicone) fill in the voids on the first pass.   Let it dry a couple hours.  Then go through with finishing layer.

Comment: Keep in mind that silicone doesn't stick to silicone. A rope caulk base might be better.

Comment: @isherwood - silicone sticks to silicone before it is cured - that is why I said wait just a couple hours.   I do the same thing for large gaps in tubs/showers.

Comment: I would use white silicone to hide the uneven area somewhat...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - never white near sinks - it stains.

Answer (score 3):

If warpage is indeed the issue your only options are a large caulk bead or a replacement unit. The laws of physics apply to home improvement as well.